# Not loading view by calling method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a user table that will link to his postings when he submits a post. (It parts works correctly)

So I have been trying to create a method in codeigniter 3. I have it set to where if the user is logged in and clicks his user name it will show all his submissions, by simply pulling from the table his user_id and then looping through his posts.

Well, I have two issues

---

when I enter in the url to call this function it wants a value for the uri. Example: localhost/CI/controller/account yet it will not load until I put something after account (account is the method name).

Like localhost/CI/controller/account/9

Also this function does not seem to work either for some reason, I do not know if it has something to do with it wanting another value.

I have researched this for the past hour with no luck.

**Controller:**

```
    public function account(){

      $data['title'] = 'Your submissions';

      $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->user_posts();

      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('users/profile', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

//view function the post by clicking on title

public function view ($slug=NULL){
  $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
  $post_id = $data['post']['id'];
  $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_comments($slug);


  if(empty($data['post'])){
    show_404();
  }
$data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');


}
```

**Model:**

```
public function user_posts (){


  $usernum = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
  $this->db->order_by('created_time','DESC');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('posts',array('customer_id ='=>'$usernum'));
  return $query->result_array();


}
$query = $this->db->get_where('posts',array('slug'=>$slug));
  return $query->row_array();
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php

echo $title;

foreach ($posts as $post): {

echo $post['title'];

}endforeach;


 ?>
```

Comment: Is there any error thrown? Have you tried to change the `return` of your model from `$query->row_array()` to `$query->result();` ?

Comment: no errors tried both, still same outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying somethings this is what corrected my issues

```
Public function user_posts (){


  $this->db->order_by('created_time','DESC');
   $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('customer_id' => $this->session->userdata('customer_id')));
  return $query->result_array();


}
```

I believe by removing the `$usernum = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');` and adding it to the query, now allows the user to call his own session id without the need to enter one into the function.

*Thanks to those that gave me input*

Answer (score 0):

**Controller :**

```
public function account($acno = "") {//changes

        $data['title'] = 'Your submissions';
        $data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->user_posts();//changes
        echo'<pre>';print_r($data);die;//changes
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

**Model :**

```
public function user_posts() {
        $usernum = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
        $this->db->order_by('created_time', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('customer_id =' => $usernum));//changes
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but this really did not correct the issue of having to enter a variable at the end of the url. I am missing something

Comment: But did you tried without parameter what have you get in your screen? I did print_r so what is your output due to my code changes, Did you see the my changes, there is a mistake in your model at $usernum

Comment: actually my way was correct, when I put the quotes back in the $usernum in the model I am able to see the information from the print_r array, but I need to fill the the url with the customer_id

Answer (score 0):

Change model function like this

```
public function user_posts (){
  $usernum = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
  $this->db->order_by('created_time','DESC');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('customer_id' => $usernum));
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

The associative array does not need `=` in `where()` or `get_where()` to get the record

Do not need single quotes with `$usernum`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your button click is set up but this is how you should do it.

**Button click page**

```
<?= site_url(); ?>controller_name/account
```

**account function in controller**

```
function account(){
//1. Check if user is Logged in
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
    //If they are not logged in, redirect them to login page or do something
}
else{
    //User is logged in so get submissions

    //Get all submissions
    $data['title'] = 'Your submissions';
    $this->data['posts']=  $this->post_model->user_posts();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/profile', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}}
```

**User posts function in Model**

```
function user_posts (){
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $ref_id=$user->id; //Gets you user id
    $this->db->where(['customer_id'=>$ref_id]);
    $this->db->order_by('created_time','DESC');
    $query=$this->db->get('posts');
    if($query->result())
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }}
```

Also, consider using [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) for your login in codeigniter as it allows you access session data easily without issues as the one you've been facing.